# Passing a NSString Variable from a UIView to a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Im trying to get the current title from a UIButton declared on a UIViewController.m store it in a NSString and then pass it on to a UITableView controller to use it as a parameter for a NSFetchRequest.

MainMenuViewController.h

```
    - (IBAction)salesMan:(UIButton *)sender;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *bPerson;
```

MainMenuViewController.m

```
    #import "MainMenuViewController.h"
    #import "DisplayResultsViewController.h"

    // more code here...

    - (IBAction)salesMan:(UIButton *)sender {

        self.bPerson = sender.currentTitle;
    }
    @end
```

DisplayResultsViewController.h

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sPerson;
```

DisplayResultsViewController.m

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController alloc]init];

        self.sPerson = mainMenu.bPerson;
        NSLog(@" %@", self.sPerson);

    }
```

The problem is that it is not passing the variable the NSLog returns "null"

Comment: This is orthogonal to your question, but following MVC best practices, you should should not be mixing your model with your view. I.e., you are setting your bPerson property (your model) from the title of your button (your View).

Comment: So what would you suggest in order to get the title from a UIButton and pass it on as a NSString to a TableViewConrtoller so it can be used as a parameter for a predicate? This is the idea : User presses button-title is sent to a table view controller for a predicate parameter-TableViewController displays the fetch request based on the button pressed.

Comment: What does the title of the button represent? Something in your model, I am assuming. Typically you'll want to store your model as a property on your view controller and reference the model for values to pass to other controllers (or passing the entire model). Stanford University have some super-awesome iOS development courses available for free in iTunes U: https://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10. The first one, **MVC and Introduction to Objective-C** should provide some good context.

Comment: Thanks I'll watch them

Answer (score 3):

> MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController
>   alloc]init];

A new instance is created in above call line, mainMenu is `alloc`ated and `init`ialised with default values.

> self.sPerson = mainMenu.bPerson;

`self.sPerson` is set a value from default initialised `mainMenu.bPerson`!!!

> NSLog(@" %@", self.sPerson);

As expected null will be printed as no value is set.

Possible Solution :

You can use any one of following:

Make the variable global, static, singleton, pass as an argument, post as notification.

Comment: So what would you suggest in order to get the title from a UIButton and pass it on as a NSString to a TableViewConrtoller so it can be used as a parameter for a predicate? This is the idea : User presses button-title is sent to a table view controller for a predicate parameter-TableViewController displays the fetch request based on the button pressed

Comment: a static or as an argument

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (not the best) is

In AppDelegate.h (moved from MainMenuViewController.h)

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *bPerson;
```

In  MainMenuViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)salesMan:(UIButton *)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [appDelegate setBPerson:sender.currentTitle];
    }
```

In DisplayResultsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController alloc]init];

        self.sPerson = [appDelegate bPerson];
        NSLog(@" %@", self.sPerson);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using a segue and pushing DisplayResultsViewController but, in your prepare for segue method on MainMenuViewController you can get an instance of the destination view controller which would be DisplayResultsViewController and set the sPerson property there:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DisplayResultsViewController *drvc = (DisplayResultsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    drvc.sPerson = self.bPerson
}
```

How are you transitioning between view controllers?

Comment: I figured it out !!
I was using a ctrl-drag segue in my story board and prepareforsegue was getting fired before the didselectrow assigned the value for the variable. I had to change to manual segue from didselectrow and assign the value to the variable before firing the segue. It was just a matter of sequence.

Comment: Personally when I use segues I don't even use didselectrow. Hopefully my answer was helpful.